# Utilizando a camera

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, iphone

Estou implementando uma tela a qual gostaria de mostrar a imagem da câmera, porém gostaria de apenas mostrar a imagem, não com funcionalidades de alternar para câmera frontal, cancelar, e nem de capturar. Há alguma maneira de fazer isso?

Até o momento só consegui mostrar com as funcionalidades, porém quero apenas mostrar a imagem em que a câmera está apontada, sem funcionalidade alguma. Atualmente utilizo o `UIImagePickerController` porém pesquisando também encontrei tutoriais que mostram com o `AVFoundation`, se puderem me esclarecer qual o melhor deles para fazer isso e como seria possível.

Código atual:

```
var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()

imagePicker.delegate = self
imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
imagePicker.view.frame = viewCamera.frame
viewCamera.addSubview(imagePicker.view)
```

Comment: No final você não quer tirar foto? Pelo o que entendi você quer pegar o vídeo da câmera e mostrá-lo em uma `UIView`, certo? Se o objetivo for esse você pode usar o `AVCaptureSession` da `AVFoundation` mesmo.

Comment: Isso, exatamente.

Answer (score 0):

Para mostrar apenas a "imagem" (o que a câmera está vendo), use o `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` (solução em `Swift 3.1`):

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class MyViewController : UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var cameraCanvasView: UIView!

    fileprivate var captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    fileprivate var movieOutput = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()
    fileprivate var videoLayer : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!

    fileprivate lazy var frontCameraDevice: AVCaptureDevice? = {
        let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) as! [AVCaptureDevice]
        return devices.filter { $0.position == .front }.first
    }()

    // Setup
    private func setup() {

        //start session configuration
        captureSession.beginConfiguration()
        captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh

        // layer
        videoLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        videoLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
        videoLayer.frame = cameraCanvasView.bounds
        cameraCanvasView.layer.addSublayer(videoLayer)

        // add device inputs
        captureSession.addInput(deviceInputFrom(device: frontCameraDevice))

        // start session
        captureSession.commitConfiguration()
        captureSession.startRunning()
    }

    // MARK: - Lifecycle Methods
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.setup()
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        videoLayer.frame = cameraCanvasView.bounds // aqui você redimensiona o AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer quando o AutoLayout atua
    }
}
```